# Replacing rows from one file with rows from other file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, replace

I am thinking   how   can I replace  a portion   of  a   file -- let's  say  lines  from  m  to n   with   lines  from   other   file  and  do this  in an  nice  manner.

I  however don't   want to  use   editors , because  this  part will   be  a  small  part in something   bigger.

Comment: You should show your own research. Hint: `head`, `tail`, `cat`, `sponge`. What exactly did you try?

Comment: which lines would you choose from the other file, or are there exactly (n-m+1) lines in that other file?

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped; don't forget to click the checkmark to indicate that the Question now has an Answer; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To replace lines 3 through 5 in file1 with lines 3 through 5 from file2:

```
ed -s file1 <<< $'3,5d\n2r !sed -n 3,5p file2\nwq'
```

For more flexibility:

```
start=3 end=5
printf '%d,%dd\n%dr !sed -n %d,%dp file2\nwq\n' $start $end $((start - 1)) $start $end | \
  ed -s file1
```

These two methods accomplish the same goal: scripted editing of file1 using lines from file2.

The ed commands are:

- `3,5d` -- delete lines 3 through 5
- `2r !sed...` -- take the output from the sed command and append it after line `2`
- `sed -n 3,5p file2` -- `p`rint only lines 3 through 5 from file2
- `wq` -- `w`rite the file back to disk and `q`uit

Comment: Tnks , this is  exactly  what I  was loocking for